# 7 circles surrounded by 12 circles

Tags: geometry

In preparation for a math contest my math teacher gave me some interesting math exercises. I am really stuck on the following task:

> Twelve coins are placed flat on a table so that their centers are the
>   edges of a regular dodecagon and the coins (circles) touch themselves
>   (adjacent). Show that 7 coins (identical) more can be put inside of the ring
>   consisting of the 12 coins.

I don't really know how to demonstrate this. It is pretty clear that a geometrical construction would work but I don't know how to explain it mathematically. I tried to draw it which is visible in the lower picture.

[image: My approach]

Any kind of help or advice will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some further hints:

[image]

Now for two consecutive pairs of circles, construct the red circles as in Figure 1.  Prove that the two constructed circles are tangent.

[image]

Finally, construct all the red circles and argue that the blue circle is tangent to each red circle and is the same size as all the other circles.

[image]

Comment: Wow, impressive. May I ask how you drew the pictures?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Draw line segments connecting the centers of touching circles.  You make a lot of equilateral triangles.  Use what you know about the angles and sides of equilateral triangles.