# Rings of Tangential Circles

Tags: geometry, circles

I looked at

[7 circles surrounded by 12 circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082457/7-circles-surrounded-by-12-circles)

and wanted to take it further, drawing a "tight" ring of $18$ circles (identical in size to the others) around the $12$, such that (a) the $18$ circles form a ring such that neighboring circles are tangential to each other and (b) if any circle in the outer ring touches a circle in the inner ring, they touch tangentially.

Further, I would like to extend it to more rings of $24, 30, 36, \dots$ circles in each ring -- all nicely tangential.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: You would have to verify that the length of the edges of the outer polygon, the length of the edges of the inner polygon, and the distance from a corner of the inner polygon to the nearest corner of the outer polygon are all equal (the diameter of the circles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen at the figure, up to $12$ surrounding circles are the congruent circles tangential.

For $12+6n, n=1,2,\dots \;$ surrounding circles, it seems more difficult to find a pattern (if any) that would make the circles tangential not only within the ring, but also "*any circle from $(n)^{th}-$ ring tangential to a circle from the previous ring*".

[image]

Comment: Your diagram looks wonderful. I suspect this is the best I can expect. Can you pl. tell me how I can draw those circles? For each circle, all I need is the (formula for its) center point. Also, for each ring, what is the (formula for the) radius of the "big" circle with its center at the origin? I see you have drawn one of those.

Comment: I drew it in GeoGebra, a free software. Without calculations. At the beginning I drew a circle, then I used exclusively transformations: symmetry, reflexion and the most often rotation. GeoGebra has all these tools. If you need coordinates or equations, they are automatically written in the left column of the GeoGebra window.

Comment: I tried my best to replicate your drawing and got the following. It seems to me that other than the first two rings with 6 and 12 circles, the circles cannot all be tangential to their two neighbors within the ring. There will be gaps. Can anyone confirm this statement?

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xhLkQ-l4LI2pVUZwVjG4oScj4_2MhpNb/view?usp=sharing) [Sorry, I don't know how to place an image in-line as you have done!]

Comment: I don't think it's possible to insert a picture into a comment. Maybe you can't put it in your question because your reputation isn't high enough. If you want, I'll do it for you.

Comment: Please do! I still do not understand why I don't get the same nice picture you have. Could you please do the GeoGebra diagram with single-pixel lines for the circles and in a larger size (maybe show only a sixth of the diagram) to see if there are any gaps?